# How to chande css property, when mouse on the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, properties

) I have a code for changing CSS class of button on web-site:

```js
window.onload = function(){
 

 var button = document.getElementById("button");

 button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
  button.classList.add("buttonclass1");
 });
 button.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
  button.classList.add("bnative1");
 })
}
```

```
I want to make like this:
 

if(mouseenter){
  button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
      button.classList.add("buttonclass1");
     });
}
else{
  button.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
  button.classList.add("bnative1");

}
```

But it doesn't work, by changing this class I want to achieve changing color. It changes, when mouse on the button, but not changed back, when it out fo te button. How can I achieve it by using JS?

Comment: I don't understand why you try to add an eventListener after an mouseEnter element.
Is that not what you want to achieve with the event listener in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the do the toggle on leave...

```
window.onload = function(){


    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
        button.classList.remove("bnative1");
        button.classList.add("buttonclass1");
    });
    button.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
        button.classList.remove("buttonclass1");
        button.classList.add("bnative1");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if all you want is adding color, you can do this with pure css.

```css
.hover-bg-blue:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="hover-bg-blue">Hello</button>
```